# DMARC Help for receiving emails in gmail

Tags: spf, dkim, dmarc

I've been using PHP to send mail to my gmail account from my website for years. This very recently stopped working and the reason given by godaddy representative was "declined due to DMARC policy."

After a little bit of reading, it seems I need to add this to my DNS **but** before I can, I also have to add SPF & DKIM 48 hours prior to adding DMARC?

I'm really at a loss here. This is levels beyond my experience. A search led me to Google Workspace Admin (but I don't have a Google Workspace Admin account so none of the instructions seem possible)

I'm guessing it's just the lack of ANY dmarc policy on my domain's dns, but I'm finding it very very difficult to find help or instructions that aren't specific to some 3rd party email company's service.

Any help or direction will be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I can't help much without knowing the domain, but generally speaking SPF is quite easy to set up, DKIM is horrible, and DMARC is quite simple once you have the other two in place... Unfortunately sending through GoDaddy is generally not likely to work well even under the best circumstances as they make it very difficult to conform to gmail's very strict requirements (which gmail is also likely to ignore anyway, even if you do everything right). Sorry I don't have better news!

Comment: @Synchro Thank you so much for your honest thoughts and insight. Two of these forms are simple enough that I feel like maybe a 3rd party, turnkey ESP solution might work, and maybe even for the slightly more complicated form. But I don't need some mass-marketing email solution b.s. just something crazy simple for getting form data to a gmail account. Any ideas about alternatives?

Comment: You can check your dmarc configuration at https://ops.team/dmarc